# Windows Form with Microsoft Web Browser in aspx page not working

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I am needing to show a website inside of an aspx page and that will allow the user to browse the website (like in an iFrame) and then on a specific page, click a button that will parse out the html to obtain specific values.  I've found a way to do this inside of a windows form control with Microsoft Web Browser.  The proof of concept works there.  I also found a way to host a windows form control inside of an aspx page. The problem is that the object does not show when the Microsoft Web Browser is referenced.  I created another Windows form control class without the MWB and it renders successfully in the aspx page.  I can click a button to change label text.  I would really like to use the Microsoft Web Browser control as so I can complete this project.  I do not see any security exceptions in Event Viewer.

```
//UserControl3.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using mshtml;

namespace TestWindowsFormControl
{    
    public partial class UserControl3 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            axWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.yahoo.com");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)axWebBrowser1.Document;
            label1.Text = doc.title;
        }
    }
}



    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--test5.html-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >   
 <head>       
  <title>Windows Form Control Test Page 5</title>       

 </head>   
 <body>       
  <h1>Windows Form Control3:</h1> 
  TEST   

  <object id="MyWinControl" classid="http://localhost:1445        /TestWindowsFormControl.dll#TestWindowsFormControl.UserControl3"           
          height="500" width="700"/>       
  <br/><br/>           
 </body>
</html>
```

This is one of those projects that is bizarre, but we need it to do this.  Using XMLHttpRequest is not applicable. JavaScript is not possible due to XSS security built into browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated.